# The name of a bike from a dockless bike share company?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I need a word that means the bike I ride, and the bike is one provided by a dockless bike-share company like Ford Gobike or something.

The context would be:

> I ride a ** bike.
> I prefer the ** bike by company A to that by company B

And etc.

I have searched the Internet but can only find the bike share program and don't know if there exists an exact name for such bikes. Maybe shared bike?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ride a **rental** bike.
I prefer company's A **rental** bikes rather than company's B **rental** bikes.